# Bash command inside .gitconfig file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git

I have a string (Github token) inside a file and I want this to be accessible via `gitconfig` only after I enter my keyring password.

For this I created a file `/secret/token`, and then `chmod` it to `400`. Now I add an entry to git config,

`git config --global ghi.token "!echo \"$(sudo cat /secret/ghi_token)\""`

But this creates an entry with my token visible in plain text instead. What I want instead is to ask for my password each time a program tries to access this gitconfig entry.

Comment: Unsure if I understand your problem right, but what about replacing the first and last double quote with single quotes and removing the backslashes?

Comment: @aventurin That didn't work. I got it working using [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) though.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using the [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) password manager utility.

After adding the token in `pass`, I added the following entry in the `.gitconfig`:

```
[github]
    token = "!pass github/token"
```

The way `pass` works is by encrypting the passwords using a GPG key. So every time the token is accessed `pass` will ask you to enter the passphrase of your GPG key.